# How can I match with regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

What I really want to do is to match all words what ever substring contain.it is working but I tried with one word.I don't want to match that string but any extra char added to that string I want to match.Like below

```
^(?!wallet)(car|cell phone|marbles|wallet|.*?wall.*)$
```

In above example I dont want to match with wallet but able to match with wallett.is it possible?

Comment: regex is not a language...Mr Ivar.It is a concept.No need to add that one.it is not necessary

Comment: Tags are not restricted to languages. Tags represent, relevant to the question, **topics**, not explicitely *languages* used. Besides, can you please show us a [mcve]? How are you using that regex? What is the desired output for a given input? The question is slightly unclear

Comment: I want to match waletttt.... String beacuse we are checking with contain ".*wall.*"but I don't want to match with "wallet" because we are subtracting that word

Comment: Thank you Ivar...such a nice suggestion

Comment: @ShivaGoudA try to change `(?!wallet)` to `(?!wallet$)`.

Comment: @Ivar what ever Nagaraju Thalluri mentioned in that we are not able to see * symbol at contains condition.

Comment: @ShivaGoudA I did not see that. You can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54022018/edit) their question and format it for them if you notice something like that. Keep in mind that this question is mainly for the countless others who will have the same problem as you. You will help them by fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
^(?!(wallet|nag)$)(car|cell phone|marbles|wallet|.*?wall.*)$
```

Comment: This doesn't match "wallett" as asked in the question. Also what's the `|nag` for?

Comment: Also it is always recommended too add an explanation as of why your code/expression fixed the problem. Questions here are not only for the person asking, but for any future visitors as well.

Comment: ^(?!^wallet$|^nag$)(car|cell phone|marbles|wallet|.*?wall.*|.*?ag.*)$   try this Ivar.its work fine.Shiva Goud A  ask only one negate value but I gave multiple.If he want then he'll accept.

Comment: Not required those caps @NagarajuThalluri.u can use directly ^(?!(wallet|nag)$)(car|cell phone|marbles|wallet|.*?wall.*)$

Comment: @NagarajuThalluri Like I said, you should add an explanation of why your code/expression fixed the problem. It nice that OP solved their problem, but we expect high quality and good explanations for future visitors as well. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your Regex is that the negative lookahead will match everything starting with "wallet". "wallett" also starts with "wallet" so it will be matched and therefore (as it is a *negative* lookahead) excluded.

You can fix that by adding the `$` anchor to be sure it only matches wallet with nothing after it.

So your regex will become this:

```
^(?!wallet$)(car|cell phone|marbles|.*?wall.*)$
```

(Note that the latter "wallet" in your regex can be removed as it is equal to the negative lookahead so it will never match.)

You can see a live example [here](https://regex101.com/r/jwJr0n/1).